Reset sidenote counter after each page
I am sure, someone has already worked out, how to reset the sidenotes package's sidenote-counter after each page. If this is you, thank you in advance, for your comment/answer ;)
Originally, I parted from an intent using the perpage package. However, as became apparent through @MadyYuvi's answer following @daleif comment, a succinct solution can be given using only latex base's hook system which is documented in base/lthooks-doc.pdf:
\AddToHook{shipout}{\setcounter{sidenote}{1}}
As @egreg's answer highlights, resetting the sidenote counter in this way is problematic if one wishes to reference the sidenote from within the text, as without additional adjustment, the reference generated before the page shipout is not updated.
I think the accepted answer should ideally address both concerns, despite my lack of foresight when originally framing the question.
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
See the sidenote \ref{xxx} on page \pageref{xxx}.
\kant[1][1-2]\sidenote{First Page. Note 1} \kant[2]
\kant[3][1-2]\sidenote{First Page. Note 2} \kant[4]
See the sidenote \ref{xxx2} on page \pageref{xxx2}.
\kant[5-6] \sidenote{Second Page. Note 1\label{xxx2}}
\kant[10][1-2]\sidenote{Second Page. Note 2\label{xxx}} \kant[11]
\end{document}

Original framing of the question (conditional on usage of perpage package)
From the following, I would expect the numbering in the margin notes, however, \MakePerPage{sidenote} does not increment correctly on the first page.
I am sure, someone has already worked around this issue. If this is you, thank you in advance, for your comment/answer ;)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{sidenote}

\begin{document}
    \kant[1]    
    \sidenote{First Page. Note 1}
    \kant[2]
    \sidenote{First Page. Note 2}
    \kant[1-3]    
    \sidenote{Second Page. Note 1}
\end{document}


do they increment correctly on other pages for you? because they do not for me. for example, adding some to page 2, I get 2, 1, 2, 3.

the problem, I guess, is that marginal notes move and latex has a hard time with this generally. your code produces warnings about the notes being moved, for example. this probably accounts for the misnumbering on page 2. it is odder that the numbering doesn't increment on page 1.

@cfr Yes you are right, thank you for pointing that out. I amended the question and included a second sidenote on page two.

For strange reasons, the sidenotes package starts the counter from 1 and steps the counter after the sidenote has been produced.
You can fix it. The example shows that a \label inside the \sidenote argument refers to the correct place.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{sidenote}

\setcounter{sidenote}{0}
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotemark { o }{%
  \@sidenotes@multichecker
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}
    {\refstepcounter{sidenote}\@sidenotes@thesidenotemark{\thesidenote}}
    {\@sidenotes@thesidenotemark{#1}}%
  \@sidenotes@multimarker
}

\RenewDocumentCommand \sidenotetext { o o +m }{%
  \IfNoValueOrEmptyTF{#1}{%
    \@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}~#3}%
  }{\@sidenotes@placemarginal{#2}{\textsuperscript{#1}~#3}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See the sidenote \ref{xxx} on page \pageref{xxx}.

\kant[1][1-2]\sidenote{First Page. Note 1} \kant[2]

\kant[3][1-2]\sidenote{First Page. Note 2} \kant[4]

\kant[5-6]

\kant[10][1-2]\sidenotemark \sidenotetext{Second Page. Note 1\label{xxx}} \kant[11]

\end{document}


If you want to use hyperref and make correct links,
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\MakePerPage{sidenote}
\newcommand{\theHsidenote}{\thepage-\arabic{sidenote}}

[the rest is the same]


I like this attempt, @egreg, as it anticipates a not yet existing need (referencing of sidenotes from within the text) ;) Thank you for your time.
The only problem with this solution is the mismatch between numbers in the text and numbers in the margin.
Using \AddToHook{shipout}{\setcounter{sidenote}{1}} spares loading another package, however, the reference shows the wrong sidenote number, as I suppose it is produced before the shipout of the page? Could the reference counter be corrected at shipout?

‹For strange reasons, the sidenotes package starts the counter from 1 and steps the counter after the sidenote has been produced.› This appears to ensure the number within the main body and the number on the sidenote being in sync.

@DanielZuluaga Seems to be fixed now. The counter must be stepped when \sidenotefootnotemark is issued.

Instead of perpage, you can try with atbegshi package, and the MWE is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{sidenotes}

\usepackage{atbegshi}%%
\AtBeginShipout{%
\setcounter{sidenote}{1}%
 }%


\begin{document}

\kant[1]    
    \sidenote{First Page. Note 1}
    \kant[2]
    \sidenote{First Page. Note 2}
    \kant[1-3]    
    \sidenote{Second Page. Note 1}
\end{document}


Isn't that basically one of the doc hooks there days?

Perfect, thank you very much, @MadyYuvi, for your help! Thank you, @daleif, for your comment. Section 3 of base/usrguide.pdf mentions the hook system documented in base/lthooks-doc.pdf which in turn references the newest shipout interface which appears to be based on Heiko Oberdiek's atbegshi package.
So a contemporary solution could also be: \AddToHook{shipout}{\setcounter{sidenote}{1}}
